# Can I remove a demarcation point for a telco that no longer exists?

Tags: telephone, service

Awhile back we had a new electrical service put in, and they put in a whole new service mast and the works. But the old service mast is still sitting there because there are other services connected to it. One is the Spectrum cable internet and I've been fighting with their electrical service about it. But the other one is a telco demarcation point for an analog phone line. I know the demarcation points are the property of the company and so forth, but as far as I can tell the telco that installed this no longer exists and none of the telcos I've contacted have wanted to come out and move or remove it.

So in this specific situation, where there is no longer mains voltage going to the mast, and no telcos want to take responsibility for the box, can I remove it? If not, who else can I call?

EDIT: I realized that the cable from the demarcation point is still connected back to the pole. I thought I had previously seen that it was disconnected. I'll have to convince a telco to do something about it.

Comment: Where are you located? For safety purposes, NOTHING should be attached to or using the electrical service mast other than your electrical service wires.

Comment: Which telco? Most of those that no longer exist DO have companies that bought their stuff, and they didn't go out and replace it with differently branded boxes when they did. In some cases there are 4 or 5 generations of who bought what from whom to sort through. Do you have a picture of this setup you could [edit] in? it IS very unusual to have anything actually attached to (not just near) the actual service mast.

Comment: Is there a communications (phone) outlet through your cableco box?

Comment: Removing the point of connection may violate code as 1 is required in many areas. Yes even if not currently in use.

Comment: If a storm brought down your copper pairs nobody would ever notice.  Just sayin'.  And the demarc goes to the electronics bin at your recycling depot.  @edbeal there are regs requiring a home to have phone service???

Comment: @jay613, yes I got hit on this quite a few years back, the owner wanted to do all his own low voltage I did not think of it but called for the final on the electrical and the inspector would not sign off because the 1 com port was not installed, he had another inspection up the road so I dropped a box with a bond to the conduit at the meter. He passed the job, nothing actually connected but the box and ground were there. (That’s all he needed to see was the box and ground).

Comment: I can see that if he "did his own low voltage" AND if that work included internal wiring that, at the time, was unavoidably destined to be connected to POTS lines, the inspector might have flagged that.  I cannot see that any town  has the authority to force you to subscribe to telephone service. In 2021, I'm not sure what you would even legislate.   A plastic box with fiber termination in it would be grounded how??  Anyway, I'm suggesting that experience of yours may not apply here.

Comment: FYI I discarded the POTS termination box I had on the wall and severed the copper after it had been in disuse for at least 8 years.  That was 8 years ago.  Then about 4 years ago someone knocked over the pole in front of my house, severing the far end of the same cable.  Telco guy later knocked on my door to "confirm" that I would not mind if he didn't bother to reconnect it.  But his face said "you're not going to f*'n make me do  that are you?"   I'm reluctant to instruct OP to Just Do It in an answer but I think there's way too much concern here.

Comment: Here's what some people might do: remove the POTS box and cut their wire as far back to the pole as possible.  Cut down the old mast with the Cable line still attached to it.  Remove it from the mast, still intact, get rid of the old mast then call Cable to fix their "fallen line" and call Telco to tell them there is a stray wire dangling from their pole.  There needs to be a place on your house (not the new mast) where they can attach the cable overhead and they'll also need to connect grounding to it not far from that.

Comment: This sounds like a question for Law.SE, not DIY.SE. Asking whether you can remove municipal equipment owned by another entity is a legal matter.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the help center.